# How to get value from option select?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How can I put value in mysql from option value?
Here is my code from file "visitor_model.php".

```
public function month_visitor() {

    $month_query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM data_visitor WHERE MONTH(date)=X');

    return $month_query->result();

}
```

and this is my option code from file "visitor_table.php"

```
<div class="row text-center">
 <h1 id="visitor_table">Visitor Table</h1>

<form action="<?php echo site_url('month_visitor');?>" method="get">
 <div>
  <label for="nomor" class="col-md-2">
    Month :
  </label>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <select name="month" class="form-control" id="month">
      <option>All</option>
      <option value='1'>January</option>
      <option value='2'>February</option>
      <option value='3'>March</option>
      <option value='4'>April</option>
      <option value='5'>May</option>
      <option value='6'>June</option>
      <option value='7'>July</option>
      <option value='8'>August</option>
      <option value='9'>September</option>
      <option value='10'>October</option>
      <option value='11'>November</option>
      <option value='12'>December</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to fill X from

```
$month_query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM data_visitor WHERE MONTH(date)=X');
```

with value from option. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP just bind parameter `month` into query as `$this->input->get('month')`:

```
$month_query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM data_visitor WHERE MONTH(date)=?', array($this->input->get('month')));
```

Comment: where should I bind parameter? in month_visitor()? Because when I bind parameter in month_parameter it give me some error

Comment: It already binded in `$this->db->query(...);` See https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html (paragraph **Query Bindings**)

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to mark it as accepted for the others to know this issue was solved @Lazuardi :)